# Testing office add-in development on mac?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

I have a Mac and I don't have an exchange server. I signed up for a dev account for Office 365 Business, but in Outlook I don't have the 'store' button, so I can't add any custom add-ins. It seems like it's because I'm not using an Exchange server.

I also tried using a Windows 10 VM, but probably because it's just a trial, it doesn't seem like it's possible to download office 365?

I was wondering what were the alternatives to test an outlook add-in on Mac? Can I use a free Windows VM somehow? Is there a solution to get that button without having to install an Exchange server just to test that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange server is required to use Web add-ins (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins). If you have logged in by the mail account that has not Exchange server (for example GMail), you will not be able to see the Store button.

If you just want to install and test Outlook Web Add-in you can create an Outlook e-mail account on https://outlook.live.com/ by clicking `Create Account` in the top-right corner. You will get your new new e-mail in the domain `outlook.com` which has exchange server. After logging in with your new account, the Store button will appear.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of found it by testing. One weird thing is that I re-installed outlook and deleted other accounts (I just kept the outlook.com one) before the button appeared.

Comment: In my case it showed just after switching an account.

Comment: What do you mean by 'switching accounts'? Did it work by just clicking on the 'Inbox' of the outlook.com account?

Comment: I logged out of my google acc and logged in my Outlook acc and a Store button was on the ribbon.